# What does the AppBaseTheme do in android apps

Tags: android, android-theme

I am unable to understand what happens with AppBaseTheme in Android.
In styles.xml I have the following code

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="mycolor">
    <item name="android:background">@layout/header_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dip</item>
</style>
<style name="myParentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:attr/windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
    <item name="android:attr/windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/mycolor</item>
</style>


<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml when I use android:theme="@style/myParentTheme" the color and size of the title are set to what I want to set. But the style for text fields changes to the old regular textboxes. When I use android:theme="@style/AppTheme" the UI looks very "Android-like" but my specific settings to the title do not have any effect. Removing parent="AppBaseTheme" makes the AppTheme style behave just like the myParentTheme style.

Additionally, why do I not see all R.attr elements when I do Ctrl+Space while typing in the name attribute of the Style tag?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Something that is even weird is that I don't get an error for the AppBaseTheme not being defined. It has to be a predefined theme. Where do I read about it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you choose to create an activity using the Eclipse new-project wizard, Eclipse will define `AppTheme` and `AppBaseTheme` resources for you. `AppBaseTheme` typically will have three definitions, in `res/values/`, `res/values-v11/`, and `res/values-v14/`. `AppTheme` will inherit from `AppBaseTheme`.

The intent is for you to put most of your app-specific style information in `AppTheme`, rather than inventing your own theme (e.g., `myParentTheme`). `AppBaseTheme` would mostly ensure that you are inheriting from the right OS-supplied theme (e.g., `Theme.Light` vs. `Theme.Holo.Light` vs. `Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`). You can also add version-specific style information to the appropriate `AppBaseTheme` if you wish.

> In `AndroidManifest.xml` when I use `android:theme="@style/myParentTheme"` the color and size of the title are set to what I want to set. But the style for text fields changes to the old regular textboxes.

That is because you are inheriting from `Theme.Light`, which uses the original (non-holographic) widget set.

> When I use `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` the UI looks very "Android-like" but my specific settings to the title do not have any effect.

That is because you decided to create `myParentTheme` instead of putting your style definitions into `AppTheme`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Explained it perfectly